# memory error while File I/O with python

Tags: python, memory, file-io

```
# Header
import numpy as np
import struct

# Main source code
for t in range(4):
    ## file info
    dirName = '../RawData/20150915Data_Simul_SystemReqTest/'
    seed = 101
    ene = 100
    #t = 0
    filePath = dirName + 'csv/seed' + str(seed) + '_nt_cc_t' + str(t) + '.csv'

    ## call data
    rawData = np.loadtxt(filePath, delimiter=',', skiprows=14)

    ## refine data
    for s in range(100):
        #setChk = ((rawData[:,0])//19026509.54==s)
        setChk = ((rawData[:,0]+1e9)//19026509.54==s)
        det1Chk = (rawData[:,5]!=0) & setChk
        det2Chk = (rawData[:,10]!=0) & setChk
        coinChk = det1Chk & det2Chk
        with open(dirName + 'data_' + str(ene) + 'keV_100sep/coin_' + str(ene) + 'keV_' + str(s) + '.bin', 'ab') as fcoin:
            fcoin.write(struct.pack('f'*(len(coinChk.nonzero()[0])*10), *rawData[coinChk, 1:].flatten().tolist()))
        with open(dirName + 'data_' + str(ene) + 'keV_100sep/evtN_' + str(ene) + 'keV_' + str(s) + '.bin', 'ab') as fevtN:
            #evtNdataL = np.int32(rawData[setChk, 0]).flatten().tolist()
            evtNdataL = np.int32(rawData[setChk, 0]+1e9).flatten().tolist()
            evtNdataL.extend(det1Chk[setChk]+(det2Chk[setChk]*2))
            evtNdata = np.array(evtNdataL).reshape([2,len(evtNdataL)/2])
            evtNdataL = evtNdata.T.flatten().tolist()
            fevtN.write(struct.pack('i'*len(evtNdataL), *evtNdataL))
        with open(dirName + 'data_' + str(ene) + 'keV_100sep/tst1_' + str(ene) + 'keV_' + str(s) + '.bin', 'ab') as ftst1:
            ftst1.write(struct.pack('f'*(len(det1Chk.nonzero()[0])), *rawData[det1Chk, 5].flatten().tolist()))
        with open(dirName + 'data_' + str(ene) + 'keV_100sep/tst2_' + str(ene) + 'keV_' + str(s) + '.bin', 'ab') as ftst2:
            ftst2.write(struct.pack('f'*(len(det2Chk.nonzero()[0])), *rawData[det2Chk, 10].flatten().tolist()))
        print(s)

    del rawData
    del det1Chk, det2Chk, coinChk, setChk

    print(t)
```

Hi,
I'm trying to run a file **I/O** code with python and getting trouble with it.
The code which I showed upper part of this thread reads `.csv` files and separated by column and write them on output files.

The name of files is:

```
seed101_nt_cc_t0.csv
seed101_nt_cc_t1.csv
seed101_nt_cc_t2.csv
seed101_nt_cc_t3.csv
```

each of them is `.csv` file with **10 column** and size is **3GB**.
when I run this program, computer uses my whole RAM of 10GB, and some time later, there is error message 'memory error'.

I use **intel i-5 CPU** and **10GB of RAM**.

cuz my boss coded this program and he's off for a while, and I'm not python user, I have no idea with dealing with such a big file **I/O** 
how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please check you indentation? It seems to be off.

Comment: At a guess, the files are producing data that is just too large; the initial `loadtxt` will use `sizeof(double)` * number of values (I'd need to know line counts for the inputs to say how big that is), but every time you do the `*xxx.flatten().tolist()`, whatever slice you are working with is converted to a `list` Python's `float` type (on Py 3.5 x64 this uses ~24 bytes per `float`, plus 8 bytes for the reference to it), then unpacked to a `tuple` with the same values (doubles the 8 bytes per reference costs). Depending on how many items are being unpacked, that could blow main memory.

Comment: Note: The ~24 bytes per `float` I gave ignores allocation overhead, which would be paid independently for each `float`, and could easily add 8+ bytes to the "real" cost of each `float`.